# how to display images in tensorboard when data fomat is "NCHW"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

In tensorflow, using function `tf.summary.image`, we can display images in tensorboard.

```
image( name, tensor, max_outputs=3, collections=None )
```

The data format of variable `tensor` is "NHWC", as `[batch_size, height, width, channels]`.

but when I use "NCHW" (`[batch_size, channels ,height, width]`), how to display images in tensorboard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image summary does not handle multiple memory layout, as some other tensorflow functions do. So currently, your only option is to transpose your images.

As `tf.transpose` is a somewhat heavy operation, you can limit the transposition to the number of images that are summarized only, say `summary_img_num`:

```
summary_imgs = tf.transpose(imgs[:summary_img_num], perm=[0,3,1,2])
tf.summary.image('images', summary_imgs, max_outputs=summary_img_num)
```

If you stick to `tf.summary.image`'s default `max_outputs=3`,

```
summary_imgs = tf.transpose(imgs[:3], perm=[0,3,1,2])
tf.summary.image('images', summary_imgs)
```